# PHP - Yii - dynamic properties CActiveRecord

Tags: php, yii

I have class Person which have properties `{property}_{countrycode}`. This class can have 20 properties and each property with country code. 20x3 = 60 properties defined in class. With each language I need to define them manually in class.

```
class Person extends CActiveRecord {

    public $name_sk;
    public $name_cz;     
    public $name_de;

    public static function model($className = __CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    function tableName() {
        return 'person';
    }

}
```

Question: How to generate/define these properties dynamically in class?

example:

```
public function __construct() {
    $langs = array('sk', 'cz', 'de');
    $properties = array('name', 'surname', 'age');
    foreach($langs as $lang) {
        foreach ($properties as $k => $value) {
            $this->{$value. "_". $lang} = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happns if you change `$this->{$k. "_". $lang} = null;` to `$this->{$value. "_". $lang} = null;`, as currently you are using the key which would result in something like 0_sk as opposed to name_sk

Comment: Do you have columns: name_sk, name_cz etc in table person???

Comment: @DanilaGanchar yes I have

Comment: You should consider changing your design and adding the countries in a data store of their own. It will make life so much easier for you.

Comment: @Ing.MichalHudak As I understand, you use name_de, name_cz for translations? In class Person must be just properties(like age, name etc.). Could you more explain about task? I think  community can propose more beautiful and easy way.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar I am using this class as example, to simplify code to understand. Actually in my problem, this tables is considered as Setting table, where config variables are stored, for each country separated. I don't use it for translation.

Comment: @Ing.MichalHudak however all properties should be described in rules. Because can be problems with validation. Thus exist 2 ways(If I correctly understood). First - describe all props in class Person(I think it is not good solution).Second - add class Setting and create relation between Person and Settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Yii 1.x you [can't](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.16/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php#L134). Only if you override `CActiveRecord._get()` by extending it.